# Zend Lucene Index Merge

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-search-lucene

Just migrated my PHP web app to another server with a new db and now I'm trying to migrate Lucine's Index to new server. Is it even possible to move my index to another server? and can we access the search index (that is stored on one server say server A) from another server (say server B)? If yes then where can I can info about that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can acces files on other server via LAN or using a HTTP Tunnel, but from the nature of HTTP protocol it's not possible to access and write to remote files...

Comment: But you can always try using streams, but I guess it's not possible without rewriting/extending the whole Zend_Lucene class...